# How can I have controls bound to a property change when the property changes by data received over network?

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, data-binding

I've got a class of users with some properties like name, age, gender and message
and so I have a form that in it some text boxes created dynamically for each property of each user and I bind each textbox to appropriate properties.

When the users connect to my program and change their properties the text boxes don't change.

This is my user class:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace binding_network
{
    class user : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                if (_name != value)
                {
                    _name = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        private int _age;

        public int Age
        {
            get { return _age; }
            set
            {
                if (_age != value)
                {
                    _age = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        private string _message;

        public string Message
        {
            get { return _message; }
            set
            {
                if (_message != value)
                {
                    _message = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        private string _gender;

        public string Gender
        {
            get { return _gender; }
            set
            {
                if (true)
                {
                    _gender = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }




        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my form code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BindingSource userBindingSource = new BindingSource();
    BindingList<user> userList = new BindingList<user>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ///some code to create textboxes dynamically....

        txtName.DataBindings.Clear();
        txtName.DataBindings.Add("text", userBindingSource[userIndex], "name");
        txtAge.DataBindings.Clear();
        txtAge.DataBindings.Add("text", userBindingSource[userIndex], "age");
        txtGender.DataBindings.Clear();
        txtGender.DataBindings.Add("text", userBindingSource[userIndex], "gender");
        txtMessage.DataBindings.Clear();
        txtMessage.DataBindings.Add("text", userBindingSource[userIndex], "message");
    }
}
```

And by this method, I receive the data by network

```
private void GetMessage(object obj)
{
    user user1 = (user)obj;
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int rec = user1.SocketClient.Receive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 0);
            Array.Resize(ref buffer, rec);
            if (rec > 0)
            {
                user1.Name = BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 0);
                user1.Gender = BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 80);
                user1.Age = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 96);
                user1.Message = BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 160);
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }

}
```

But after receiving the data the textboxes don't refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of code appears to be missing, but here's a few things...

The `userBindingSource` hasn't been connected to `userList`.

The binding `propertyName` and `dataMember` parameters have incorrect casing.

The `userIndex` isn't defined.

Even if it were, binding to `userBindingSource[userIndex]` doesn't allow navigation of the source (maybe you're fine with that).

So let's fix those:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BindingSource userBindingSource = new BindingSource();
    BindingList<user> userList = new BindingList<user>();
    int userIndex = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userBindingSource.DataSource = userList;
        userIndex = userBindingSource.Position;

        ///some code to create textboxes dynamically....

        txtName.DataBindings.Clear();
        txtName.DataBindings.Add("Text", userBindingSource, "Name");
        txtAge.DataBindings.Clear();
        txtAge.DataBindings.Add("Text", userBindingSource, "Age");
        txtGender.DataBindings.Clear();
        txtGender.DataBindings.Add("Text", userBindingSource, "Gender");
        txtMessage.DataBindings.Clear();
        txtMessage.DataBindings.Add("Text", userBindingSource, "Message");
    }
}
```

Assuming that `userList` has been populated, you may now navigate the `userBindingSource` like this:

```
// However you're tracking userIndex, or maybe...
// userIndex = userList.IndexOf(user1);
userBindingSource.Position = userIndex;
```

Or any of these:

```
userBindingSource.MoveFirst();
userBindingSource.MovePrevious();
userBindingSource.MoveNext();
userBindingSource.MoveLast();
```

And finally, remove the infinite `while (true)` loop in `GetMessage`.

At this point, if your data is correctly received and parsed, your `TextBox` controls should update.

**Edit...**

So you're multi-threading this, which is great.

Now we have to make sure all operations that result in a UI change are done on the proper thread.

Lets do this (assuming `GetMessage` is defined inside the `Form` class):

```
        if (rec > 0)
        {
            var name = BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 0);
            var gender = BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 80);
            var age = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 96);
            var message = BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 160);

            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                user1.Name = name;
                user1.Gender = gender;
                user1.Age = age;
                user1.Message = message;
            }));
        }
```

And this:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())));
}
```

And binding source navigation (if on a different thread):

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => userBindingSource.Position = userIndex));
```

You may also look into using the `BeginInvoke` method.

Comment: thank for your answer
yes I use `userIndex = userList.IndexOf(user1);`
but it doesn't worked.
because i use `GetMessage` method in a different thread, when the property changed the compiler throw an exception with this message:Cross-thread operation not valid. Control "" accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: thanks dear @rfmodulator for your answer,
we use multi-threading to have a lighter main-thread but in the threads we pass the main function `Action(() =>` to the main thread again.
what's the advanteges of this kind of multi-thread programming?? and is there any way to handle the methods in their own thread??

Comment: @robert This is how we marshal actions back to the UI thread to avoid the "cross-thread exception" when it results in the state of a `Control` being changed. Here, I've done everything possible in the *other* thread to minimize the load on the UI thread. There are a few different ways you might see it being done, but the basic principle is the same. This is a simple explanation, I suggest investigating the topic more.

Comment: dear @rfmodulator  what's your idea about using `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false`? is it some negetive effects on my program??
and if it possible send me some refrence for more investigation...
finally i'm sorry for my bad english
and again thank you dear @rfmodulator.

Comment: @robert Don't set `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false`, eventually your program will be unreliable, and you won't know why. The rumor is that it was introduced in .NET 2.0 to provide backwards compatibility with .NET 1.1 ...ancient history. Don't interact directly with UI components from background threads. You can search for "WinForms Multi-threading" to learn more.